# How to add a user based link in WordPress admin menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to ad a user specific menu item to the WordPress dashboard. Logged in users with a `subscriber`role anyway have reduced access, but I'd like to ad backend links to my `jobs` and `dating` and `events` dashboards.

Tried this in my functions php:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'linked_url' ); 
function linked_url() {
    add_menu_page( 'linked_url', 'External link', 'read', 'my_slug', '', 'dashicons-text', 1);
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
function  0() {global $menu;
    $menu[1][2] = "https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/";
}
```

It broke my site.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site broke because there is some syntax error in your code. When defining second function you have `function 0`. This should be `function linkedurl_function`. If you fix this, URL will be there in the admin menu.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'linked_url' );
function linked_url() {
    add_menu_page('linked_url', 'External link', 'read', 'my_slug', '', 'dashicons-text', 1);
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
function linkedurl_function() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[1][2] = "https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/";
}
```

Alternative: If you want links inside the main menu like `Dashboard`, you can use following example. In the following example, two links are added under Dashboard menu.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpso_custom_links_admin_menu');
function wpso_custom_links_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link One', 'read', 'https://www.example.com/' );
    $submenu['index.php'][] = array( 'Link Two', 'read', 'https://asdf.com/' );
}
```

Comment: Super. And how do I name the link? At the moment it just says `external link`

Comment: You can change it from `add_menu_page()` - second parameter.

Comment: Tried twice to add second link, using the same format, but my site just breaks....?

Comment: @9017 Please check updated answer.I have added alternative approach. That may help.

Comment: Should url's be in speech rather than quotation marks?